# How to store template_id that new event is derived from

Tags: civievent

I'm working on an event management framework where I want to have a set of event templates, and create events based off of those templates.

I'm trying to find a way to get at and store which template a newly created event was derived from but I can't quite figure out what to do.

I tried looking at both 
hook_civicrm_postProcess() (which has the template_id but not the new event's id)
and hook_civicrm_post() which as the newly created event id, but doesn't tell you what template it was derived from.

Can anyone think of a way to find those two values at the same time so that I can put the data in a custom field on the new event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reverse of what you're trying to do but might have the intended result:

Instead of populating the custom field *after* event creation, how about adding the custom field to your event template and populating it there?

Comment: That's a good idea, I can see how that would work.  But there's a second problem.  I need to be able to programmatically fetch events with the api, but custom data doesn't filter events via api. I was planning on populating a Drupal field using CiviCRM entity 2.x, but to do this I need to be able to get at both bits of data in some hook or another....

Comment: i could get at it with: hook_civicrm_custom(), good idea on setting a value for a custom field in the template...